# Using the after_save callback to modify the same object without triggering the callback again (recursion)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I add an after_save callback to an ActiveRecord model, and on that callback I use update_attribute to change the object, the callback is called again, and so a 'stack overflow' occurs (hehe, couldn't resist).

Is it possible to avoid this behavior, maybe disabling the callback during it's execution? Or is there another approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One workaround is to set a variable in the class, and check its value in the after_save.

1. Check it first. (if var)
2. Assign it to a 'false' value before calling update_attribute.
3. call update_attribute.
4. Assign it to a 'true' value.
5. end

This way, it'll only attempt to save twice.  This will likely hit your database twice, which may or may not be desirable.

I have a vague feeling that there's something built in, but this is a fairly foolproof way to prevent a specific point of recursion in just about any application.
I would also recommend looking at the code again, as it's likely that whatever you're doing in the after_save should be done in before_save.  There are times that this isn't true, but they're fairly rare.

Comment: Awesome! I've searched for a built in approach too, but so far it seems there's none, but it would be great if you could set a special property to tell Rails to temporarily suspend that callback... your approach is kind of like that do, so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11):

Could you use the before_save callback instead?

Answer (score 11):

I didn't see this answer, so I thought I'd add it in case it helps anyone searching on this topic. (ScottD's without_callbacks suggestion is close.)

ActiveRecord provides `update_without_callbacks` for this situation, but it is a private method.  Use send to get access to it anyway. Being inside a callback for the object you are saving is exactly the reason to use this.

Also there is another SO thread here that covers this pretty well:
[How can I avoid running ActiveRecord callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632742/how-can-i-avoid-running-activerecord-callbacks)

Answer (score 7):

Also you can look at the plugin [Without_callbacks](http://github.com/cjbottaro/without_callbacks).  It adds a method to AR that lets you skip certain call backs for a given block.
Example:

```
def your_after_save_func
  YourModel.without_callbacks(:your_after_save_func) do
    Your updates/changes
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6):

Check out how [update_attribute](http://api.rubyonrails.com/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001365) is implemented.  Use the send method instead:

```
send(name.to_s + '=', value)
```

Answer (score 4):

This code doesn't even attempt to address threading or concurrency issues, much like Rails proper.  If you need that feature, take heed!

Basically, the idea is to keep a count at what level of recursive calls of "save" you are, and only allow after_save when you are exiting the topmost level.  You'll want to add in exception handling, too.

```
def before_save
  @attempted_save_level ||= 0
  @attempted_save_level += 1
end

def after_save
  if (@attempted_save_level == 1) 
     #fill in logic here

     save  #fires before_save, incrementing save_level to 2, then after_save, which returns without taking action

     #fill in logic here 

  end
  @attempted_save_level -= 1  # reset the "prevent infinite recursion" flag 
end
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use before_save, you can modify any additional parameters before the save is completed, meaning you won't have to explicitly call save.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks guys, the problem is that I update *other* objects too (siblings if you will)... forgot to mention that part...

So before_save is out of the question, because if the save fails all the modifications to the other objects would have to be reverted and that could get messy :)

Answer (score 2):

The trick is just to use `#update_column`:

- Validations are skipped.
- Callbacks are skipped.
- updated_at/updated_on are not updated.

Additionally, it simply issues a single quick update query to the db.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_columns

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too.  I need to save an attribute which depends upon the object id.  I solved it by using conditional invocation for the callback ...

```
Class Foo << ActiveRecord::Base  
    after_save :init_bar_attr, :if => "bar_attr.nil?"    # just make sure this is false after the callback runs

    def init_bar_attr    
        self.bar_attr = "my id is: #{self.id}"    

        # careful now, let's save only if we're sure the triggering condition will fail    
        self.save if bar_attr
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this is because of not specifying attr_accessible in models. When update_attribute wants to edit the attributes, if finds out they are not accessible and create new objects instead.On saving the new objects, it will get into an unending loop.

Answer (score 0):

I had a need to `gsub` the path names in a block of text when its record was copied to a different context:

```
attr_accessor :original_public_path
after_save :replace_public_path, :if => :original_public_path

private

def replace_public_path
  self.overview = overview.gsub(original_public_path, public_path)
  self.original_public_path = nil

  save
end
```

The key to stop the recursion was to assign the value from the attribute and then set the attribute to nil so that the `:if` condition isn't met on the subsequent save.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `after_save` in association with `if` as follows:

```
after_save :after_save_callback, if: Proc.new {
                                                //your logic when to call the callback
                                              }
```

or

```
after_save :after_save_callback, if: :call_if_condition

def call_if_condition
  //condition for when to call the :after_save_callback method
end
```

`call_if_condition` is a method. Define the scenario when to call the `after_save_callback` in that method