# How can I avoid running ActiveRecord callbacks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have some models that have after_save callbacks. Usually that's fine, but in some situations, like when creating development data, I want to save the models without having the callbacks run. Is there a simple way to do that? Something akin to...

```
Person#save( :run_callbacks => false )
```

or

```
Person#save_without_callbacks
```

I looked in the Rails docs and didn't find anything. However in my experience the Rails docs don't always tell the whole story.

UPDATE

I found [a blog post](http://web.archive.org/web/20120701221754/http://blog.viarails.net/2009/1/29/disabling-callbacks-in-an-activerecord-data-migration) that explains how you can remove callbacks from a model like this:

```
Foo.after_save.clear
```

I couldn't find where that method is documented but it seems to work.

Comment: If you're doing something destructive or expensive (like sending emails) in a callback I recommend moving this out and triggering it separately from the controller or elsewhere. This way you won't "accidentally" trigger it in development, etc.

Comment: solution you accepted is not working for me. I am using rails 3. i am getting an error like this:--undefined method `update_without_callbacks' for #<User:0x10ae9b848>

Comment: yaa that blog post worked....

Comment: Related question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449019/rails-4-skip-callback#answer-19449936

Comment: Wouldn't `Foo.after_save.clear` remove callbacks for the entire model? And then how do you propose to restore them?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

This solution is Rails 2 only.

I just investigated this and I think I have a solution. There are two ActiveRecord private methods that you can use:

```
update_without_callbacks
create_without_callbacks
```

You're going to have to use send to call these methods. examples:

```
p = Person.new(:name => 'foo')
p.send(:create_without_callbacks)

p = Person.find(1)
p.send(:update_without_callbacks)
```

This is definitely something that you'll only really want to use in the console or while doing some random tests. Hope this helps!

Comment: its not working for me. I am using rails 3. i am getting an error like this:--undefined method `update_without_callbacks' for #<User:0x10ae9b848>

Comment: Your suggestion is not working but the blog post mentioned in the update part is working..

Comment: This will skip validations, too.

Comment: I have another solution for any version of Rails. It works for us well. Check it out in my blog post: http://railsguides.net/2014/03/25/skip-callbacks-in-tests/

Answer (score 248):

Use `update_column` (Rails >= v3.1) or `update_columns` (Rails >= 4.0) to skip callbacks and validations. Also with these methods, `updated_at` is **not** updated.

```rb
#Rails >= v3.1 only
@person.update_column(:some_attribute, 'value')
#Rails >= v4.0 only
@person.update_columns(attributes)
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_column

**#2: Skipping callbacks that also works while creating an object**

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :skip_some_callbacks

  before_validation :do_something
  after_validation :do_something_else

  skip_callback :validation, :before, :do_something, if: :skip_some_callbacks
  skip_callback :validation, :after, :do_something_else, if: :skip_some_callbacks
end

person = Person.new(person_params)
person.skip_some_callbacks = true
person.save
```

**UPDATE (2020)**

Apparently Rails [has always supported `:if` and `:unless` options](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/aae37bb4f7edd6a1820e420a60560369c6064f33/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb#L50), so above code can be simplified as:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :skip_some_callbacks

  before_validation :do_something, unless: :skip_some_callbacks
  after_validation :do_something_else, unless: :skip_some_callbacks
end

person = Person.new(person_params)
person.skip_some_callbacks = true
person.save
```

Comment: looks like it works with 2.x as well, and there are a host of other methods that operate similarly: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#skipping-callbacks

Comment: This doesn't address `:create_without_callbacks` :(  How can I run something similar to that?  (Worked in Rails2, removed in Rails3).

Comment: Assuming `@person` is a variable in a controller somewhere, this solution means that people reading your model class won't be able to understand the callbacks. They will see `after_create :something_cool` and will think "great, something cool happens after create!". To actually understand your model class, they will have to grep through all your controllers, looking for all the little places where you have decided to inject logic. I don't like it >o< ;;

Comment: replace `skip_callback ..., if: :skip_some_callbacks` with `after_create ..., unless: :skip_some_callbacks` to run this properly with after_create.

Answer (score 30):

---

Updated:

@Vikrant Chaudhary's solution seems better:

```
#Rails >= v3.1 only
@person.update_column(:some_attribute, 'value')
#Rails >= v4.0 only
@person.update_columns(attributes)
```

---

My original answer :

see this link:  [How to skip ActiveRecord callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342761/how-to-skip-activerecord-callbacks)

in Rails3,

assume we have a class definition:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :generate_nick_name
end
```

Approach1:

```
User.send(:create_without_callbacks)
User.send(:update_without_callbacks)
```

Approach2: 
When you want to skip them in your rspec files or whatever, try this:

```
User.skip_callback(:save, :after, :generate_nick_name)
User.create!()
```

NOTE: once this is done, if you are not in rspec environment, you should reset the callbacks:

```
User.set_callback(:save, :after, :generate_nick_name)
```

works fine for me on rails 3.0.5

Answer (score 30):

If the goal is to simply insert a record without callbacks or validations, and you would like to do it without resorting to additional gems, adding conditional checks, using RAW SQL, or futzing with your exiting code in any way, consider using a "shadow object" pointing to your existing db table. Like so:

```
class ImportedPerson < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'people'
end
```

This works with every version of Rails, is threadsafe, and completely eliminates all validations and callbacks with no modifications to your existing code. You can just toss that class declaration in right before your actual import, and you should be good to go. Just remember to use your new class to insert the object, like:

```
ImportedPerson.new( person_attributes )
```

Comment: Best solution EVER. Elegant and simple!

Comment: This worked really nicely for me because it was something I wanted to do only in test, to simulate database "before" state, without polluting my production model object with machinery to optionally skip callbacks.

Comment: By far the best answer

Comment: Upvoted because it shows how to work-around existing rails constraints and helped me understand how the whole object MVC really works. So simple and clean.

Answer (score 21):

rails 3:

```
MyModel.send("_#{symbol}_callbacks") # list  
MyModel.reset_callbacks symbol # reset
```

Comment: Nice. Also MyModel.skip_callback(:create, :after, :my_callback) for precise control.. see ActiveSupport::Callbacks::ClassMethods docs for all the lobang

Comment: Useful info: the 'symbol' in `reset_callbacks` is not `:after_save`, but rather `:save`. 
http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.9/ActiveSupport/Callbacks/ClassMethods/reset_callbacks

Answer (score 17):

You could try something like this in your Person model:

```
after_save :something_cool, :unless => :skip_callbacks

def skip_callbacks
  ENV[RAILS_ENV] == 'development' # or something more complicated
end
```

**EDIT:** after_save is not a symbol, but that's at least the 1,000th time I've tried to make it one.

Comment: I really think this is the best answer here. This way the logic that determines when the callback is skipped is available in the model, and you don't have crazy code fragments everywhere pealing back the business logic, or circumventing encapsulation with `send`. KOODOS

Answer (score 11):

You can use `update_columns`:

```
User.first.update_columns({:name => "sebastian", :age => 25})
```

> Updates the given attributes of an object, without calling save, hence skipping validations and callbacks.

Answer (score 7):

The only way to prevent all after_save callbacks is to have the first one return false.

Perhaps you could try something like (untested):

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :skip_after_save

  def after_save
    return false if @skip_after_save
    ... blah blah ...
  end
end

...

m = MyModel.new # ... etc etc
m.skip_after_save = true
m.save
```

Comment: I love trying (untested). Thrill ride.

Comment: Tested and it works. I think this is a very good and clean solution, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Looks like one way to handle this in Rails 2.3 (since update_without_callbacks is gone, etc.), would be to use update_all, which is one of the methods that skips callbacks as per [section 12 of the Rails Guide to validations and callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#skipping-callbacks).

Also, note that if you are doing something in your after_ callback, that does a calculation based on many association (i.e. a has_many assoc, where you also do accepts_nested_attributes_for), you will need to reload the association, in case as part of the save, one of its members was deleted.

Answer (score 5):

The most `up-voted` answer might seem confusing in some cases.

You can use just a simple `if` check if you would like to skip a callback, like this:

```
after_save :set_title, if: -> { !new_record? && self.name_changed? }
```

Answer (score 4):

with Rails 6 you can now use the [insert methods](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-insert_all)

from the documentation:

> Inserts multiple records into the database in a single SQL INSERT
> statement. It does not instantiate any models nor does it trigger
> Active Record callbacks or validations. Though passed values go
> through Active Record's type casting and serialization.

Answer (score 3):

https://gist.github.com/576546

just dump this monkey-patch into config/initializers/skip_callbacks.rb

then

`Project.skip_callbacks { @project.save }`

or the like.

all credit to the author

Answer (score 3):

A solution that should work across all versions of Rails without the use of a gem or plugin is simply to issue update statements directly. eg

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "update table set foo = bar where id = #{self.id}"
```

This may (or may not) be an option depending on how complex your update is. This works well for eg updating flags on a record from ***within*** an after_save callback (without retriggering the callback).

Comment: Not sure why the downvote, but I still think the above answer is legitimate. Sometimes the best way to avoid issues with ActiveRecord behaviour is to avoid using ActiveRecord.

Comment: Upvoted on principle to counter the -1. We just had a production issue (with a long story behind it) that required us to create a new record (not an update) and firing callbacks would have been catastrophic. All the above answers are hacks whether they admit it or not and going to the DB was the best solution. There ARE legitimate conditions for this. Though one should beware of SQL injection with the `#{...}`.

Answer (score 3):

I needed a solution for Rails 4, so I came up with this:

app/models/concerns/save_without_callbacks.rb

```
module SaveWithoutCallbacks

  def self.included(base)
    base.const_set(:WithoutCallbacks,
      Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base) do
        self.table_name = base.table_name
      end
      )
  end

  def save_without_callbacks
    new_record? ? create_without_callbacks : update_without_callbacks
  end

  def create_without_callbacks
    plain_model = self.class.const_get(:WithoutCallbacks)
    plain_record = plain_model.create(self.attributes)
    self.id = plain_record.id
    self.created_at = Time.zone.now
    self.updated_at = Time.zone.now
    @new_record = false
    true
  end

  def update_without_callbacks
    update_attributes = attributes.except(self.class.primary_key)
    update_attributes['created_at'] = Time.zone.now
    update_attributes['updated_at'] = Time.zone.now
    update_columns update_attributes
  end

end
```

in any model:

```
include SaveWithoutCallbacks
```

then you can:

```
record.save_without_callbacks
```

or

```
Model::WithoutCallbacks.create(attributes)
```

Answer (score 2):

When I need full control over the callback, I create another attribute that is used as a switch. Simple and effective:

Model:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :do_stuff, unless: :skip_do_stuff_callback
  attr_accessor :skip_do_stuff_callback

  def do_stuff
    puts 'do stuff callback'
  end
end
```

Test:

```
m = MyModel.new()

# Fire callbacks
m.save

# Without firing callbacks
m.skip_do_stuff_callback = true
m.save

# Fire callbacks again
m.skip_do_stuff_callback = false
m.save
```

Answer (score 1):

None of these points to `without_callbacks` plugin that just does what you need ...

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :do_something_before_save

  def after_save
    raise RuntimeError, "after_save called"
  end

  def do_something_before_save
    raise RuntimeError, "do_something_before_save called"
  end
end

o = MyModel.new
MyModel.without_callbacks(:before_save, :after_save) do
  o.save # no exceptions raised
end
```

http://github.com/cjbottaro/without_callbacks works with Rails 2.x

Answer (score 1):

```
# for rails 3
  if !ActiveRecord::Base.private_method_defined? :update_without_callbacks
    def update_without_callbacks
      attributes_with_values = arel_attributes_values(false, false, attribute_names)
      return false if attributes_with_values.empty?
      self.class.unscoped.where(self.class.arel_table[self.class.primary_key].eq(id)).arel.update(attributes_with_values)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sneaky-save gem: https://rubygems.org/gems/sneaky-save.

Note this cannot help in saving associations along without validations. It throws error 'created_at cannot be null' as it directly inserts the sql query unlike a model. To implement this, we need to update all auto generated columns of db.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a plugin that implements update_without_callbacks in Rails 3:

http://github.com/dball/skip_activerecord_callbacks

The right solution, I think, is to rewrite your models to avoid callbacks in the first place, but if that's impractical in the near term, this plugin may help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Rails 2. You could use SQL query for updating your column without running callbacks and validations.

```
YourModel.connection.execute("UPDATE your_models SET your_models.column_name=#{value} WHERE your_models.id=#{ym.id}")
```

I think it should work in any rails versions.

Answer (score 1):

For creating test data in Rails you use this hack:

```
record = Something.new(attrs)
ActiveRecord::Persistence.instance_method(:create_record).bind(record).call
```

https://coderwall.com/p/y3yp2q/edit

Answer (score 1):

#### For custom callbacks, use an `attr_accessor` and an `unless` in the callback.

Define your model as follows:

```
class Person << ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :skip_after_save_callbacks

  after_save :do_something, unless: :skip_after_save_callbacks

end
```

And then if you need to save the record without hitting the `after_save` callbacks you defined, set the `skip_after_save_callbacks` virtual attribute to `true`.

```
person.skip_after_save_callbacks #=> nil
person.save # By default, this *will* call `do_something` after saving.

person.skip_after_save_callbacks = true
person.save # This *will not* call `do_something` after saving.

person.skip_after_save_callbacks = nil # Always good to return this value back to its default so you don't accidentally skip callbacks.
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to be able to do this in development? Surely this will mean you are building your application with invalid data and as such it will behave strangely and not as you expect in production.

If you want to populate your dev db with data a better approach would be to build a rake task that used the faker gem to build valid data and import it into the db creating as many or few records as you desire, but if you are heel bent on it and have a good reason I guess that update_without_callbacks and create_without_callbacks will work fine, but when you are trying to bend rails to your will, ask yourself you have a good reason and if what you are doing is really a good idea.

Comment: I'm not trying to save without validations, just without callbacks. My app is using callbacks to write some static HTML to the filesystem (sort of like a CMS). I don't want to do that while loading dev data.

Comment: Was just a thought, I guess whenever in the past I've seen this kind of question it's trying to get around stuff for bad reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use validation hooks instead of callbacks. For example:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate_on_create :do_something
  def do_something
    "something clever goes here"
  end
end
```

That way you can get the do_something by default, but you can easily override it with:

```
@person = Person.new
@person.save(false)
```

Comment: This seems like a bad idea - you should use things for their intended purpose. The last thing you want is your validations to have side effects.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to have a separate model for such manipulations, using the same table:

```
class NoCallbacksModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'table_name_of_model_that_has_callbacks'

  include CommonModelMethods # if there are
  :
  :

end
```

(Same approach might make things easier for bypassing validations)

Stephan

Answer (score 0):

Something that should work with all versions of `ActiveRecord` without depending on options or activerecord methods that may or may not exist.

```
module PlainModel
  def self.included(base)
    plainclass = Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base) do
      self.table_name = base.table_name
    end
    base.const_set(:Plain, plainclass)
  end
end


# usage
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PlainModel

  validates_presence_of :email
end

User.create(email: "")        # fail due to validation
User::Plain.create(email: "") # success. no validation, no callbacks

user = User::Plain.find(1)
user.email = ""
user.save
```

TLDR: use a "different activerecord model" over the same table

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when I wanted to run a Rake Task but without running the callbacks for every record I was saving.
This worked for me (Rails 5), and it must work for almost every version of Rails:

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :skip_callbacks
  before_create :callback1
  before_update :callback2
  before_destroy :callback3

  private
  def callback1
    return true if @skip_callbacks
    puts "Runs callback1"
    # Your code
  end
  def callback2
    return true if @skip_callbacks
    puts "Runs callback2"
    # Your code
  end
  # Same for callback3 and so on....
end
```

The way it works is that it just returns true in the first line of the method it skip_callbacks is true, so it doesn't run the rest of the code in the method.
To skip callbacks you just need to set skip_callbacks to true before saving, creating, destroying:

```
rec = MyModel.new() # Or Mymodel.find()
rec.skip_callbacks = true
rec.save
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 7, we can do something like this to skip all callbacks -

```
person.save!(callbacks: false)
```

Answer (score -8):

Not the cleanest way, but you could wrap the callback code in a condition that checks the Rails environment.

```
if Rails.env == 'production'
  ...
```