# How to skip callbacks on Mongoid Documents?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, mongoid

My question is similar to this one [How to skip ActiveRecord callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342761/how-to-skip-activerecord-callbacks) but instead of AR I'm using Mongoid, It seems like that isn't implemented yet in the current version of Mongoid, so I'd like to know what should be an elegant solution to implement it. (if necessary).

Comment: which version of Mongoid ? Mongoid 1.9.0 or Mongoid 2.0.0.beta ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes you can!

Mongoid is built on ActiveModel and ActiveModel has a [skip_callback function](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-skip_callback). You can use `skip_callback` like this:

```
# skip the callback
MyModelClass.skip_callback(:save, :before, :ensure_foo_is_not_bar)

# rescue any errors to ensure callback is restored afterwords
begin
  my_model_instance.update_attributes :foo => 'bar'
rescue
  puts "Error from 'my_model_instance.update_attributes': #{$!}"
end

# restore the callback for future calls
MyModelClass.set_callback(:save, :before, :ensure_foo_is_not_bar)
```

I'm using this without a hitch in a big app. For more info, see this blog post by Jeff Kreeftmeijer:

http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2010/disabling-activemodel-callbacks/

Comment: It would be great if there was a way to turn off all callbacks like you would turn off validations: `u.save!(validate: false)`  would be `u.save!(callbacks: false)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, this work for skip callbacks in my test suite.

Comment: This can lead to a really big issue. If the code between the `skip_callback` and `set_callback` generates some error, the callback can be skipped forever and never setted again. The server would need to be restarted to make this work again. And the worst: this callback will be skipped for the entire class! That means all of the instances of that class will have this callback skipped! Be careful if you want to use this. I had big issues on my app while using this approach to `skip` and `set` callbacks.

Comment: Thanks, Victor, for pointing out this issue. I've updated the code in my answer to use a `resuce` block to prevent errors from disabling the callback.

Answer (score 23):

It might be easier to use the Mongoid atomic operations (set, unset, etc):

https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/tutorials/mongoid-persistence/#atomic

These do not fire callbacks.

Edit: Mongoid 3 says they do not fire callbacks.  I am seeing them fire callbacks in Mongoid 2 though. So YMMV

Comment: This works in Mongoid 4 as well. Was having a helluva time trying to figure out how to inc a counter in the parent document with cascading callbacks set to true.

Answer (score 19):

I ended up using Brian Armstrong's suggestion and simply calling

```
person.set(name:"Robert Pulson")
```

in my after save callback.

Answer (score 3):

Often this comes up when you want to do an update without firing all callbacks on a large volume of items. This can be done by descending to the driver:

Replacing 'foo' by 'bar' in the 'x' field.

```
User.all.each do |u|
  User.collection.where({ _id: u.id }).update({ 
    "$set" => { :x => u.x.gsub('foo', 'bar') 
  })
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I search on the code. And there are no way to avoid callback in Mongoid. In both version 1.9 and 2.0.

You need made a patch or a feature request about that.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I was also reviewing the 2.0.0.beta and there is no skipping callbacks support ... let's see how AR does it and then implement it on my version of mongoid.