# Mongoid validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I'm using Mongoid 3.1

I'm trying to automatically create a slug (`self.name.parameterize`) when a new record is created. I want to ensure the slug is present and unique. I have the following code which is working. However, I don't think it's right because `generate_slug` is called every time the model is saved, creating a lot of overhead. However, if I use before_create, how can I still validate uniqueness and presence? Mongoid doesn't have a `before_validation_on_create` like ActiveRecord.

```
before_validation :generate_slug
field :slug
index({ slug: 1}, { unique: true })
validates :slug, :presence => true, :uniqueness => {:case_sensitive => false}
attr_readonly :slug

private

def generate_slug
self.slug ||= name.parameterize unless name.blank?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

How about [skipping callbacks conditionally](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-skip_callback) if name was not changed.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046919/how-to-skip-callbacks-on-mongoid-documents).