# Skipping relation callbacks on Mongoid

Tags: ruby, callback, mongoid, activemodel

There seems to be a way for skipping [non-relation callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046919/how-to-skip-callbacks-on-mongoid-documents), but I tried the following and the relation callbacks are still being fired:

```
class Foo
    include Mongoid::Document

    has_and_belongs_to_many :elements, after_add: :add_callback
    field :name   

    after_update :do_update

    def do_update
       Foo.skip_callback(:save, :after, :add_callback)
       self.elements << Element.create(name: "NEW ELEMENT")
       Foo.set_callback(:save, :after, :add_callback)
    end

    def add_callback
        Foo.skip_callback(:save, :after, :add_callback)
        self.elements << Element.create(name: "ANOTHER NEW ELEMENT")
        Foo.set_callback(:save, :after, :add_callback)
    end
end
```

This times outs because `add_callback` is being continuously fired, and so the `skip_callback` doesn't seem to be working.

How do I skip the relation callback?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to suppress `do_update` somewhere? You're only suppressing `add_callback`. I'd probably bypass Mongoid completely and operate on `Foo.collection`.

Comment: @muistooshort I think `do_update` is fine. If the user edits the `name` field, then `do_update` fires and adds a new element. The problem is that when `do_update` adds a new element, the `add_callback` fires, and since that also adds a new element, another `add_callback` fires... and so on until the program crashes. What should happen is the update adds a new element, and then it skips the `add_callback`. Can you give an example on how to bypass using `Foo.collection`? Will it fire validations on the model?

Comment: You'd use [Moped](http://mongoid.org/en/moped/) methods to bypass Mongoid completely and talk straight to the database, no validations or other Mongoid-ism will be done. The problem as I see it is that `do_update` and `add_callback` effectively call each other so once you enter either method its all over because there's no way out. So `do_update` needs to suppress `add_callback` and vice versa, no? Needing to suppress callbacks suggests a design problem though. What are `Foo` and `Element` and what is the real problem you're trying to solve with these callbacks?