# ignore before_update when save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, save, before-filter

some case I don't want execute before_update. please help me.

case A: in case I want used before_update

```
obj = Object.find(id)
obj.save
```

but case B I don't want used before_update

```
obj = Object.find(id)
obj.save # in case I want used before_update
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update_without_callbacks and create_without_callbacks are private methods. These methods will not call any callbacks.

```
obj = Object.find(id)
obj.send(:update_without_callbacks)

obj = Object.new(:name => 'foo')
obj.send(:create_without_callbacks)
```

Comment: Don't do this! There is a reason why these methods are private. You should never rely on internal API or your application won't work in case of internal refactoring.

Comment: Only works in Rails 2.  Check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342761/how-to-skip-activerecord-callbacks)

Answer (score 3):

The method `#save` accepts a Hash of option. To skip validations:

```
obj.save(:validate => false)
```

This is the documented way to skip validations using the public API. Don't try to use send to call internal methods or your application might not work in the future.