# How can I update attributes in after_save without causing a recursion in rails 2.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, save, ruby-on-rails-2

I've got a model which has a video attached with [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip). After it saves I use the saved video to generate a thumbnail. I need to do this after every save, even when a new video hasn't been uploaded, because the user can change the time where the thumbnail is captured.

I am currently using after_post_process to do this, but it will only generate the thumbnail when uploading a file (this is a callback which is part of Paperclip).

I would ideally use an after_save callback like this:

```
after_save :save_thumbnail
def save_thumbnail
  #generate thumbnail...
  self.update_attributes(
    :thumbnail_file_name => File.basename(thumb), 
    :thumbnail_content_type => 'image/jpeg'
  )
end
```

Unfortunately update_attributes calls save, which then calls the before_save callback causing an infinite loop. Is there a simple way to circumvent this behaviour?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could wrap it in a conditional, something like:

```
def save_thumbnail
  if File.basename(thumb) != thumbnail_file_name
    self.update_attributes(
      :thumbnail_file_name => File.basename(thumb), 
      :thumbnail_content_type => 'image/jpeg'
    )
  end
end
```

That way it would only run once.

Comment: Currently the thumbnail always has the same name as the video, so I'd have to encode the time in the thumbnail name, but that should work, thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Any `update_attribute` in an `after_save` callback will cause recursion, in Rails3+.
What should be done is:

```
after_save :updater!
# Awesome Ruby code
# ...
# ...

private

  def updater!
    self.update_column(:column_name, new_value) # This will skip validation gracefully.
  end
```

Here is some documentation about it: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#skipping-callbacks

Answer (score 8):

Rails 2:

```
Model.send(:create_without_callbacks)
Model.send(:update_without_callbacks)
```

Rails 3:

```
Vote.skip_callback(:save, :after, :add_points_to_user)
```

See this question:

[How to skip ActiveRecord callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342761/how-to-skip-activerecord-callbacks)

Comment: What if there are other callbacks that do need to be run?

Comment: This might well mess with Paperclip's callbacks, but useful nonetheless! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can(and should) check if you actually need to update the thumbnail:

```
after_save :save_thumbnail
def save_thumbnail
  if capture_time_changed? #assuming capture_time contains time when the thumbnail has to be captured
    #generate thumbnail...
    self.update_attributes(
      :thumbnail_file_name => File.basename(thumb), 
      :thumbnail_content_type => 'image/jpeg'
    )
  end
end
```

Here you can read more about 'dirty' attributes: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Dirty

Although I'm not sure if it still can see the attribute changes in after_save. You can use a member variable to indicate changes in case it can't.

Answer (score 0):

You can run it as a `before_save` instead.

After it has been validated, update the thumbnail, then let it go on to be saved, but just use the assignment methods

```
before_save :save_thumbnail
def save_thumbnail
  self.thumbnail_file_name = File.basename(thumb), 
  self.thumbnail_content_type = 'image/jpeg'
end
```

Since that won't call save, you wont recurse, but it will immediately be saved after the method exits.

Something like that should work, unless there is an explicit reason you need it in after save.

Since you are not updating a separate object, but the same one, this will save you a database call as well. This is How i do timestamps and things like that too.

Comment: This doesn't work because the uploaded file won't have been processed by Paperclip yet, this is why I have been using after_post_process.