# Skipping :after_add callback when adding objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, callback

I have an model with a `:has_many` with an `:after_add`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :jobs, :after_add => :invalidate_old_jobs
end
```

Now I want to add several of these objects, however I do not want to run the `:after_add` before I've added the last object (It could run, however, the method called in `:after_add` will update the same values all the time)

I have found `skip_callback`, but I cannot seem to find how to call it, with the `:after_add`.

How do I *not* run the `:invalidate_old_jobs` before I have added the last job?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [How to skip ActiveRecord callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342761/how-to-skip-activerecord-callbacks#comment17459549_5259681) to solve your given question.

But this is not a good way to go. You should optimize/fix your validation logic so that you don't need to bypass the validation process. Feel free to post your complete User and Job model here to get feedback about a better solution.