# Is there any way to skip the callbacks dynamically from controller as we did like save(false) for validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my model there is  validation and some callbacks

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :name, :email, presence: true
   after_save :send_mail

 end
```

In my controller I can skip the validation while save the data using `save(false)` or `save(:validate => false)`

can I do the same thing for callbacks

like `save(:callback => false)`

Thanks

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342761/how-to-skip-activerecord-callbacks