# How to disable ActiveRecord callbacks in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, callback

I would like to skip/disable `ActiveRecord` callbacks in, specifically, Rails 3. The following is an example solution I thought of -- creating an attribute that is defined to create the object without callbacks.

```
product = Product.new(title: 'Smth')
product.send(:create_without_callbacks)
```

The above example is similar to that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/633330/3373470), but the author said it is for *specifically* Rails 2. Is there a similar, or even better, way to do this *for Rails 3*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. See the question: [How can I avoid running ActiveRecord callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632742/how-can-i-avoid-running-activerecord-callbacks)
2. [This blog post](http://web.archive.org/web/20120701221754/http://blog.viarails.net/2009/1/29/disabling-callbacks-in-an-activerecord-data-migration) has another explanation with example.

Comment: The blog post mentioned a solution for Rails 3.  
The private create_without_callbacks method was removed in Rails 3.  Have you consider putting an exception in your callbacks?

Comment: Hum... I would like to disabled it "per instance"/"per process". The blog explains how to disable it globally.

Comment: @xpepermint the blog post I linked to in my answer shows another solution. It will work for Rails 3 AND 4.

Answer (score 0):

You may find the solution here helpful: http://manuelvanrijn.nl/blog/2012/01/12/disable-rails-before-slash-after-callback/

**TL;DR** - If you are doing this production, it may be helpful to create a class (see blog post) to keep your code DRY. Otherwise, if you do this once, or even in testing (like myself), you can simply do the following:

```
SomeModel.skip_callback(:save, :before, :before_action)
SomeModel.skip_callback(:save, :after, :after_action)
```

The blog post provides a nice list of callbacks the above method will work with.

This will work in both Rails 3 and Rails 4. As noted by a comment, if you have to disable callbacks, you may want to ask yourself *why* you need those callback. To expand, disabling callbacks are questionable only in production. If you need to disable them in testing (which is what I am doing myself), it is acceptable... Especially since Rails 4 core deprecated the use of observers.

Answer (score -1):

```
SomeModel.skip_callback(:save) do 
   somemodel_instance.save
end
```

tested: **Rails 4.2.1**