# Skipping callbacks and validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way to skip callbacks and validation by doing something along these lines in Rails 3?

```
Object.save(:validate => false, :skip_callbacks => true)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered something like that before and I used this:

```
Model.send(:create_without_callbacks)
Model.send(:update_without_callbacks)
```

Answer (score 15):

```
Object.save(:validate => false)
```

works as you would expect.  So far as I know you cannot turn off callbacks (unless you return false from a before_ callback, but that then aborts the transaction).

Answer (score 3):

For skipping callbacks in Rails 3, you can use `update_all` for your given purpose.

Source: [update_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all)

The full list for skipping callbacks are here:

- decrement
- decrement_counter
- delete
- delete_all
- find_by_sql
- increment
- increment_counter
- toggle
- touch
- update_column
- update_all
- update_counters

Source: [Skipping Callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#skipping-callbacks)

Answer (score 2):

Skipping callbacks is a bit tricky. Some plugins and adapters add their own "essential" callbacks (acts_as_nested_set, oracle_enhanced_adapter as examples).

You could use the `skip_callback` and `set_callback` methods in checking which ones you'd be able to skip.

Some custom class methods could help:

```
  def skip_all_callbacks(klass)
    [:validation, :save, :create, :commit].each do |name|
      klass.send("_#{name}_callbacks").each do |_callback|
        # HACK - the oracle_enhanced_adapter write LOBs through an after_save callback (:enhanced_write_lobs)
        if (_callback.filter != :enhanced_write_lobs)
          klass.skip_callback(name, _callback.kind, _callback.filter)
        end
      end
    end
  end



  def set_all_callbacks(klass)
    [:validation, :save, :create, :commit].each do |name|
      klass.send("_#{name}_callbacks").each do |_callback|
        # HACK - the oracle_enhanced_adapter write LOBs through an after_save callback (:enhanced_write_lobs)
        if (_callback.filter != :enhanced_write_lobs)
          klass.set_callback(name, _callback.kind, _callback.filter)
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to update the record skipping all callbacks and validations you could use `update_columns` passing the attributes hash. This method will update the columns direct on database.

For example:

`object.update_columns(name: 'William')`

If you want to create a new object, unfortunately I think there is no method to skip both validations and callbacks. `save(:validate => false)` works for validations. For callbacks you could use `skip_callback` but be careful, your code probably will not be thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html details a small list of methods that avoid callbacks and validations - none of these include 'save' though.

However, the point of validations and callbacks is to enforce business logic. If you're avoiding them - you should ask yourself why.

See also: [How can I avoid running ActiveRecord callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632742/how-can-i-avoid-running-activerecord-callbacks)