# Best way to save dependent classes in each one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, associations

I have 2 Ruby on Rails model classes A and B which are dependent and I want to save one when I save the other.

My current solution is to use a temporary attribute like on [How to avoid ActiveRecord model double saving?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703797/how-to-avoid-activerecord-model-double-saving)
But is there a better way ?

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :b

  attr_writer :save_b_values

  def save_b_values
    return @save_b_values if defined? @save_b_values
    true
  end

  before_save do
    save_b_values = false

    if save_b_values
      b.each do |bi|
        bi.save!
      end
    end
  end

  after_save do
    save_b_values = true
  end
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :a, autosave: true
end
```

Comment: How are you updating the Bs? Are they being updated in the model, or are they being updated in the controller. Is it possible to use nested attributes?

Comment: I would like to do both of them.