# Mongoid - set a field to true for at least one document

Tags: ruby, sinatra, mongoid

I want there **always** to be **at least one** document in database which has a field titled "`selected`" set to true. How do I do that? Most probably I have to use callbacks, but which one: `before (or after) _create, _upsert, _update`?

And how can I ensure that it will be set to true whatever operation executes: create, update, upsert...? I guess that would not be right to create a callback for each of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[after_save always runs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.9/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#available-callbacks) after create & update

so you could do:

```
after_save do |your_class|
  your_class.update_column(:selected, true) unless YourClass.where(selected: true).exists?
end
```

NB./ [update_column should not fire the after_save again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7386222/26679)!

Comment: will not be there an infinite recursion?

Comment: Good point. There's a link on that NB./ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632742/how-can-i-avoid-running-activerecord-callbacks/7386222#7386222

Comment: will not be there an infinite recursion?