# In Rails can I save a record without it calling my callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback, rails-activerecord

When I do `my_record.save` can I pass a parameter or something to tell the record to not call it's Callback?  Below is the callback I have set for my object.

```
class Measurable < ActiveRecord::Base

   after_save :summarize_measurables_for_player

   # ...

   def summarize_measurables_for_player
     # ...   
   end

end
```

**Edit**

This callback is used for when someone changes a value on measurable, then it calculates the preferred value for the `Measurable_Type` and then it stores that value on a column of another object.  This allows me to retrieve the information much faster.  I however, don't want this to be called when I import information.  Because it would then summarize after each change.  It would be a faster process to import all the information and then summarize all the values at once I would think.

Comment: You might find [this question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632742/how-can-i-avoid-running-activerecord-callbacks) useful. Skip down to the answer with 166 points. I found a lot of useful hits Googling "rails skip save callback". :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, I'd add an attr_accessor to the model and skip this method if set to true.

```
class Measurable < ActiveRecord::Base

   after_save :summarize_measurables_for_player, :unless => :skip_summarize

   attr_accessor :skip_summarize

   # ...

   def summarize_measurables_for_player
     # ...   
   end

end
```

Then in the import, you can set `:skip_summarize => true` in the attributes of the imported object.