# Explanation of methods for skipping callbacks in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I have Video and Playlist models. To boost the process of displaying a thumbnail for the Playlist - I've made a column named 'thumbnail'. I would like it to be updated anytime when playlist is updated (because there's a lot of such situations in different parts of my app), so I tried to use callback `after_update`:

```
Class Playlist < ApplicationRecord

  after_update :set_thumbnail


  def set_thumbnail
    video_thumbnail = Video.find(self.content[0]).thumbnail
    self.update(thumbnail: video_thumbnail)
  end
end
```

Of course I've got endless cycle.

Rails docs just list methods for skipping callbacks (e.g. decrement, decrement_counter , etc.), so I have no idea how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

[after_commit callback](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods/after_commit) is more suitable here. This will be run after changes are saved to database unlike `after_update` which execute callbacks before actual commit to database.

```
after_commit :set_thumbnail, on: [:update]
```

Comment: Still I would like to know about skipping callbacks.

Comment: [Check this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632742/how-can-i-avoid-running-activerecord-callbacks)

Answer (score 0):

May be it is better to use `before_save` here?

```
Class Playlist < ApplicationRecord

  before_save :set_thumbnail, on: :update


  def set_thumbnail
    video_thumbnail = Video.find(self.content[0]).thumbnail
  end
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately. it doesn't improve the situation: update when update when update... until 'stack level's too deep'.

Comment: @a-ta-ta, please, check my answer carefully. You don't need to use `self.update` here, just set an attribute