# How do I run only before or after callbacks on an active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Lets say I have the following class

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

before_save :before_callback_1, :before_callback_2, :before_callback_3
after_save :after_callback_1, :after_callback_2, :after_callback_3

end
```

I want to do something like:

```
foo = Foo.new

foo.run_before_save_callbacks
foo.update_columns(...)
foo.run_after_save_callbacks
```

Is there some active record method that allows me to do this or do I need to get a list of all the callbacks and filter them and run them manually?

Comment: It seems to me that this question has the answer that you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632742/how-can-i-avoid-running-activerecord-callbacks. What do you think?

Comment: @PedroPaiva unfortunately that question is about not invoking callbacks, my question is about manually invoking them

Comment: Why do you want to run the before and after callbacks manually instead of using `update` that would trigger those callbacks automatically?

Comment: @spickermann it appears that trying to simplify my example by using update_columns has actually caused more confusion since everyone is fixating on that instead of the actual root of the question. In my real world example I am using insert_all since there are thousands of records that I insert at a time that have callbacks that need to be executed so I'm trying to manually execute all the before callbacks on each record, insert all, then run all the after callbacks

Answer (score 2):

You can trigger calling `before_save` *and* `after_save` callbacks like this:

```
foo.run_callbacks(:save) { foo.update_columns(...) }
```

See [`ActiveSupport::Callbacks`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Callbacks.html#method-i-run_callbacks).

Answer (score 1):

After reading your comment replies I have a better idea of what you're looking for. At the least, if you want to run `before_save` callbacks manually, you can get a list of them like this:

```
callbacks    = Foo._save_callbacks.select{ |callback| callback.kind == :before }
method_names = callbacks.map(&:filter)
```

Similarly for `after_save` callbacks:

```
callbacks    = Foo._save_callbacks.select{ |callback| callback.kind == :after }
method_names = callbacks.map(&:filter)
```

(I actually use this in minitest to make sure our models have the expected callbacks.)

Comment: Thanks! It looks like manually getting the callbacks and running them myself is what I need to do as there is no built in rails method to do it unfortunately

Comment: Please keep in mind, `has_many :models, dependent: :null` will create `after_destroy` callbacks. Not sure about other callbacks like `after_save`. Just something to be aware, especially if you are planning on calling them manually

Comment: The last piece would be calling each method until one returns false or nil:
`method_names.reduce(true) { |continue, m| continue ? foo.send(m) : continue }`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `update_columns` use `update` (or the alias `update_attributes`) to accomplish the update while also running callbacks. It would take the place of your 3 lines there.

```
#foo.run_before_save_callbacks # No need, already run by `update`.
foo.update(...)
#foo.run_after_save_callbacks  # No need, already run by `update`.
```

Comment: I understand that update invokes the callbacks for me, that was just an example using `update_columns`.